# Refactoring - Android String Extraction Question

Tags: android, string, localization

I have localized almost all of application with only a few outliers remaining.  Below is an example of one.  How might I do this without creating 2 separate @string variables?

```
builder.setTitle("Version " + getAppVerName() + " Changes");
```

Where getAppVerName() =

```
public String getAppVerName() {
    String text;
    try {
        text = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        text = "Version Not Found";
    }
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format strings in strings.xml.

```
<string name="version">Version %1$s Changes</string>

builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.version, getAppVerName()));
```

Comment: I like yours better than my replace :)  Can you give me the 30 second primer on %1$s?  %1 is the returned value from getAppVerName().  Does $s mean it's a string?

Comment: can you elaborate on the use of %1$s?

Comment: s means its a string d means its a number. the 1 means its the first arg. The second would be %2$s.

Comment: I have shared this with several very seasoned developers today.  None of them had every seen that notation used.  All of them, myself included, are very excited about implementing it.  Learn something new every day: check.  Now I can celebrate St. Patrick's Day without guilt.  Thanks Robby!

Answer (score 2):

You could return immediately but I think you code is fine the way it is.

```
try {
        return getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return "Version Not Found";
    }
```